# добавление оригинальных яндекс текстов с помощью php. проблема с urlencode

Tags: php, curl, яндекс-вебмастер

Тексты добавляются в виде:

> %D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9+%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81+%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F+%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F+%D0%BD%D0%B0+%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5+%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81+%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8B%0A%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%

хотя добавленный через форму на https://webmaster.yandex.ru/site/{мой-сайт}/info/original-texts/
отображается нормально.

Перед добавлением обрабатываю  текст через urlencode(), т.к. это требование яндекса.

**сам вопрос**: как сделать добавленный текст читабельным? Подозреваю, что каких-то заголовков для curl недозадал или неверно задал, но сам не пойму...

вот код, которым добавляю:

```
$text = 'пробный текс для добавления на оригинальные яндекс тексты
пробный текс для добавления на ...
';
$text = strip_tags($text);
$text = html_entity_decode($text);
$text = str_replace('&', '&amp;', $text);

$response = sendTextToYandex($text,$user_id,$host_list['hosts'][4]['host_id'],$token);
var_dump($response);


/////////////функции отправки текста//////
function sendTextToYandex($text,$user,$host_id,$token) {
        $url = "/v3/user/".$user."/hosts/". $host_id . "/original-texts/";
        $text = urlencode($text);
        $text = "<Data><content>{$text}</content></Data>";
        $additionalHeaders = array( 'Accept: application/xml',
                                    'Content-Type: application/xml',
                                    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($text),
                                    'Authorization: OAuth '.$token                      
                                   );
        $curlOptions = array(CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 30, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $text);
        $response = performYandexWebmasterApiRequest($url,$token, 'POST', $curlOptions, $additionalHeaders,$text);
    return $response;
    }

# Функция непосредственной подготовки на выполнения запроса добавления уникального текста
function performYandexWebmasterApiRequest($url,$token, $requestType = 'POST', $curlOptions = array(), $additionalHeaders = array(),$text) {
        $headers = array(); 

        $headers = array_merge($headers, $additionalHeaders);
        $requestOptions = array(
            CURLOPT_URL => 'https://api.webmaster.yandex.net' . $url,
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 1,
            CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 30,
            CURLOPT_HEADER => 1,
            CURLOPT_POST => 1,
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $text
        );
        $response = getPage($requestOptions);
    return $response;
}


function getPage($curlOptions = array()) {

        try {
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt_array($ch, $curlOptions);
            $result = curl_exec($ch);
            $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
            $res =  array('result' => $result, 'info' => $info,'opt' => $curlOptions);

            if (false === $res) {
                throw new Exception(curl_error($ch), curl_errno($ch));

            }
            return $res;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
                trigger_error(sprintf(
                'Curl failed with error #%d: %s',
                $e->getCode(), $e->getMessage()),
                E_USER_ERROR);
        }    
}
/////////////функции отправки текста//////
```

функции взяты из инета и перепилены под себя, но, как видно, не до конца)
чего я не учел?
Спасибо

Comment: попробуйте не обрабатывать, у яндекса довольно  много ошибок в документации

Comment: вы имеете ввиду обработку через urlencode()? Пробовал уже - выдает 400 ошибку - Bad request и ничего не добавляет

Comment: А файл скрипта в какой кодировке сохранен?

Comment: UTF-8 у скрипта

Answer (score 0):

в общем обошел я эту проблему.
У яндекса оказывается есть класс для работы с их api: https://github.com/yandex/webmaster.api
(вообще не понимаю как я мог пропустить его) ), но на его основе я допилил свою реализацию. С xml ушел на json и вот как вышло, может кому поможет (только функции отправки):

```
/////////////функции отправки текста//////  вызов внизу страницы
function sendTextToYandex($text,$user,$host_id,$token) {
        $url = "/v3/user/".$user."/hosts/". $host_id . "/original-texts/";
        ///$text = urlencode($text);
        $data = array('content'=> $text);
        $data_json = json_encode($data);
        $additionalHeaders = array( "Accept: application/json", "Content-type: application/json",
                                    'Authorization: OAuth '.$token                      
                                   );                          


        $curlOptions = array(CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 30, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $text);
        $response = performYandexWebmasterApiRequest($url,$token, 'POST', $curlOptions, $additionalHeaders,$data_json);
    return $response;
    }
    # Функция непосредственной подготовки на выполнения запроса добавления уникального текста
function performYandexWebmasterApiRequest($url,$token, $requestType = 'POST', $curlOptions = array(), $additionalHeaders = array(),$text) {
        $headers = array(); 


        $headers = array_merge($headers, $additionalHeaders);

          $requestOptions = array(
            CURLOPT_URL => 'https://api.webmaster.yandex.net' . $url,
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers,
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $text
        );

        $response = getPage($requestOptions);
    return $response;
}


function getPage($curlOptions = array()) {

        try {
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt_array($ch, $curlOptions);

            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROTOCOLS, CURLPROTO_HTTP | CURLPROTO_HTTPS);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REDIR_PROTOCOLS, CURLPROTO_HTTP | CURLPROTO_HTTPS);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

            $result = curl_exec($ch);
            $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
            $res =  array('result' => $result, 'info' => $info,'opt' => $curlOptions);

            if (false === $res) {
                throw new Exception(curl_error($ch), curl_errno($ch));

            }
            return $res;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
                trigger_error(sprintf(
                'Curl failed with error #%d: %s',
                $e->getCode(), $e->getMessage()),
                E_USER_ERROR);
        }    


        }
/////////////функции отправки текста//////
```